# Change value of date input jquery

Tags: jquery, date, onclick

So here is the thing, I need to ask users for minimum and maximum birthdate.

THe user have a choice of having no maximum birthdate. In that case, I want the default value of the tag to be 1900-01-01.

But for some reason, it doesn't get put the value. It keeps value at null....

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K5HRq/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#max_date_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var input_data = $('#birthdate_max').val == "1900-00-00" ? "{{{ date('Y-m-d') }}}" : "1900-00-00";
            $('#birthdate_max_div').toggle();
            $(this).text( $(this).text() == "No max date" ? "Yes max date" : "No max date");
            $('#birthdate_max').val(input_data);
            console.log(input_data);
            console.log($('#birthdate_max').val());
        });
    });
```

Thanks a lot,
Ara

Comment: $('#birthdate_max').val == "1900-00-00" ? or 1900-01-01.

Comment: Wow.... -.- Sometimes I wonder if I am the dumbest human being alive....Thanks a lot!

Comment: You want `$('#birthdate_max').val()`. `val` is a method. Also, might I suggest using `disable` instead? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/K5HRq/7/)

Comment: @AraSivaneswaran if you have solved the problem yourself please answer your own question to assist future user seeking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb mistake.

```
 ('#birthdate_max').val == "1900-00-00" ? "{{{ date('Y-m-d') }}}" : "1900-00-00";
```

should be:

```
 ('#birthdate_max').val == "1900-01-01" ? "{{{ date('Y-m-d') }}}" : "1900-01-01";
```